# upload chrome extension to store including native application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have my first brand new google chrome extension, which I'd like to upload to the chrome web store. The thing is that my extension is using native messaging via stdio to a c++ exe. The extension also required a registry key to be installed.

Is it possible to upload the required files to the chrome web store (including exe and dll dependency)? Is there a way to automate the installation of the registry key (required to send messages from chrome extension js to exe), and register dll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind chrome-extensions (and native messaging) is to limit the giant security hole that is NPAPI: to create a divide between the browser and the desktop that runs it. For this reason, you'll need to perform two separate installations: one for the extension and another for the native code.

- To the best of my knowledge, you can't bundle the binary with the extension.  But you might be able to (partially) do it the other way around: have the native code *also* install the extension:
- There *is* a way to partially automate the process of installing the extension: you can pre-load the extension via the registry. This only applies to extensions on the chrome web-store (CWS). I believe this requires to reboot chrome. And of course the user is notified that an extension was installed. see here - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions
- There's also something called "inline installation" - not quite "automatic", but this should make it easier for your users to install the extension from "within" your site (as opposed to the CWS). The extension still needs to be hosted on the CWS, but the user needs not navigate there.
  see here - https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation (and especially the line section - about verified site - which requires that you register your site with Google - and thus may render this technique useless to you)